# Angular Reactive Form - Unique field validator in edit mode

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular 8 application with Reactive Forms.

I have a form with some controls and I use it for both create and update operations:

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl({value: this.editMode ? this.id : '', disabled: false}, [
    Validators.required,
    this._uniqueIdValidator.bind(this)
  ]),
  label: new FormControl(this.editMode ? this.label : '', [
    Validators.required
  ])
});
```

The `id` control has a custom validator to check its uniqueness:

```js
private _uniqueIdValidator(control: FormControl) {
  if (this.collection.findIndex(item=> item.id === control.value) > -1) {
    return {duplicate: true};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now, everything works fine when adding a new item.
However, when I open the form in edit mode, it raises the `duplicate` error and I am unable to save the item **with the same values as before.**

I have added the following code in my validator:

```js
if (this.id !== '' && this.id === control.value) {
  // value is identical, so the form is valid
  return null;
}
```

But I'm curious if there is another method to implement it.

Thanks!

---

Example:
Assuming that my data collection is:

```
[
 {id: 'id1', label: 'Foo'},
 {id: 'id2', label: 'Bar'},
 {id: 'id3', label: 'Another'}
]
```

and I want to **edit** the label of the item with `id3`, my form raises an error that id field is duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just extend the if check in the validator to also check if `this.id` (if exists) is other than / same as  `control.value`. I also changed `findIndex` to `find` here:

```ts
private _uniqueIdValidator(control: FormControl) {
  if (control.value !== this.id && this.collection.find(item => item.id === control.value)) {
    return { duplicate: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4rptl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: performance wise, I would change the order of the conditions. If `control.value !== this.id` is `false` it is not necessary to search the collection, so better skip it go to the else sentence.

Comment: @andreivictor You are absolutely correct, thanks, updated answer based on your tip :)